# Simple PHP variable equal to a string containing some html tags resulting in NULL apon echo call

Tags: php, string

I have a simple variable, `$var`, that is equal to a string: `'<div id="body">'`. I later want to use that string in a function, but it strangely returns nothing. If I try to echo

`gettype($var);`

, it returns `NULL`. I've tried `htmlentities()` and `htmlspecialchars()`, but neither have fixed the problem. Is it a problem with the text inside the string? Thanks for any answers.

Update: here is all the code you should need:

```
$textToBeginSearchAfter = '<div id="body">';

//snippet from a foreach loop that grabs a file from a certain directory

$fileContents = file_get_contents($file);
$contentsLength = strlen($fileContents);
$startSearchPos = strpos($fileContents, $textToBeginSearchAfter);
//here's where I try to echo it: return nothing
echo $textToBeginSearchAfter."<br>";
//here i try to echo the data type: returns null
echo gettype($textToBeginSearchAfter)."<br>";
$startSearchLength = strlen($textToBeginSearchAfter);
$startSearch = $startSearchPos + $startSearchLength;
$endSearchPos = strpos($fileContents, $textToEndSearchBefore);
$endSearchLength = strlen($textToEndSearchBefore);
$endSearch = $endSearchPos - $endSearchLength;
$contentsSearchLength = $contentsLength - ($contentsLength - $endSearch) - $startSearch;
$trimmedContents = strip_tags(substr($fileContents, $startSearch, $contentsSearchLength));
```

This code is part of a search function and I'm just trying to narrow down the string to search from the file inside the `<body>` tag.

Comment: There's nothing special about strings that contain HTML. Show the full code.

Comment: Definitely something in the foreach loop is overwriting the variable.

Comment: @ProfileTwist I tried echoing it before the foreach loop but it still printed nothing.